# Android/Java Calling a function from an activity that instantiated the current class

Tags: java, android

first time actually posting a question my self so i hope i'm doing this right.

In my Android Application, i've got an Activity called "SessionDetails.java". In this class i have called upon a custom class ("CustomExpandableView.java") that creates a custom expandable list layout for me. It does this by creating different instances of the class "ParentSlice.java" and subsequently creating different instances of the class "ChildSlice.java" for every one of those ParentSlices. The ChildSlices all have some text data on it, but some also have an ImageView on it.

So far i've got it all working just fine, the list expands and collapses exactly as it is supposed to and the ImageViews are displayed only when the list is instantiated from "SessionDetails.java" and not when instantiated from "Session.java", while the icon shows only on those slices that should have the icon.

What i want to achieve, however, is that when the button on the ChildSlice is pressed, some things in the orginal Activity of SessionDetails change.

What i've tried so far is to pass along the context of the class that instantiates it (parse "this"), but since it can be called from either "SessionDetails" or "Session" i can not use the this, because the context variable is determined at run time.

I've also tried to set up a custom event handler "OnPlotRequestListener" but i got stuck on that as well as i could not understand how to fire the custom event et cetera.

So bascially my question is this: How do i call a function/method from the class that instantiated my current class? Can i do it via a standard OnClick method? If so, how!

SImplistic Example:

```
Public Class A extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_session_details_screen);

        B myB = new B(this);
    }

    public void doStuffToActivity()
    {    }
}

Public Class B 
{
    public B(Context context)
    {
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context)
        icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {   
                 //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE FUNCTION OF THE ACTIVITY.

                 //This does not work.
                 context.doStuffToActivity(); 

                 //Making a static method in A wont work, because then i can't alter, for example, a TextView on the activity.

                 //I've tried to create my own event handler, but couldn't figure it out.

            }
        });
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me how i should go about this, i would be very happy.

On request i could post some code, but i think that would only make it confusing.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Cast `context` as the Activity class.

Comment: Wow. Well i feel incredibly stupid now. Thanks immensely for your answer though.

Comment: You could pass an interface implemented in the parent class to the child while creating it. And call a method from the parent via the interface in the child.